# How to start the my own sample in Qualcomm's Vuforia AR for android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

Hi Everyone,
            I have started Augment reality application in android .I have seen many frameworks but i'm following the VUforia developer site.In that developer site they provide some sample .i have run that sample but my problem is if i want to start my own sample How to start development .Can any one help me .

Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly try to share what you want to make from those Samples. There are six samples in that project. For Understanding and development, the basic sample which is most helpful is

```
ImageTarget Project
```

With this project you can change the data set and load your own data set other then the tea pot.
You can also apply scaling, translation and rotation on touch in this sample project.

After that `Virtual Button Project` helps you to interact virtually and you can even convert it from virtual to physical touch interaction .

There is a project of `Video playback project` you can use it to load your own videos or images randomly.
It depends on you that what you want to start with.
All your starting points are available in all 6 projects